# json not returning data

Tags: javascript, json

g,day. could someone help me make sense of why my code is not returing the results to json? i am sure there is an error in my code but cannot seem to find it. what is supposed to happen is the values of $dept and $box are supposed to be returned in an alert, but this does not happen. thanks

```
<?php

function runSQL($rsql) {
 $hostname = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "";
 $dbname   = "sample";
 $connect = mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password) or die ("Error: could not connect to database");
 $db = mysql_select_db($dbname);
 $result = mysql_query($rsql) or die ('test'); 
 return $result;
 mysql_close($connect);
}
$new = 1;

$items = rtrim($_POST['items'],",");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `boxes` WHERE id IN ($items)";
$result = runSQL($sql);


$i = 0;
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   if ( $i < $rows ) {

      $dept .= $row['department'] . "," ;
      $box .= $row['custref'] . "," ;
   } else { 

   $dept .= $row['department'];
   $box .= $row['custref'];
   }
   $i++;
}


/*$items = rtrim($_POST['items'],",");
$sql = "UPDATE `boxes` SET status = 'Deleted' WHERE id IN ($items)";
$result = runSQL($sql);*/

//$sql = "INSERT INTO `act` (`item`) VALUES (\''.$box.'\')";
//$result = runSQL($sql);

$total = count(explode(",",$items)); 
$result = runSQL($sql);
$total = mysql_affected_rows(); 
/// Line 18/19 commented for demo purposes. The MySQL query is not executed in this case. When line 18 and 19 are uncommented, the MySQL query will be executed. 
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT" );
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate( "D, d M Y H:i:s" ) . "GMT" );
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate" );
header("Pragma: no-cache" );
header("Content-type: text/x-json");
$json = "";
$json .= "{\n";
$json .= "dept: '".$dept.",'\n";
$json .= "box: '".$box."'\n";
$json .= "}\n";
echo $json;
?>
```

the ajax

```
success: function(data){
dept = data.dept;
box = data.box;
alert("You have successfully deleted\n\r\n\rBox(es): "+data.dept+data.box);
$("#flex1").flexReload();
   }
```

Comment: **WHY** are you generating JSON yourself instead of using one of the dozens of extensions or libraries that does it for you?

Comment: habit :-) i really because of time restraints need to find the error in this code. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `boxes` WHERE id IN ($items)";
```

SQL-injection vulnerability. You must `mysql_real_escape_string` each individual item if they are strings, or ensure they are only numbers if that's what they're supposed to be (eg with `intval()`). Or use parameterised queries.

```
header("Content-type: text/x-json");
```

`application/json`.

```
$json .= "dept: '".$dept.",'\n";
```

Apart from JSON needing double-quotes around keys and string values, you would also need to JavaScript-string-literal-escape values being injected into a string. Otherwise an apostrophe/quote/backslash/newline would break the string. You can mostly do this with `addslashes()`.

But really, there's no call to be constructing your own JSON values (or other JavaScript literals). PHP gives you [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). It's simpler, faster, more reliable. Use it.

```
echo json_encode(array(
    'dept'=>$dept,
    'box'=>$box
));
```

Comment: header("Content-type: application/json");
$json .= "dept: '".$dept.",'\n";

echo json_encode(array(
    'dept'=>$dept,
    'box'=>$box
)); and it causes error: <b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined function: json_encode() i am using php4.4.7

Comment: Eek! Yeah, PHP4 doesn't have `json_encode` I'm afraid. You really need to upgrade though: PHP4 is no longer supported (and hasn't been for quite some time now); there have been loads of security holes fixed since then.

Comment: admins choice. i am just humble servant :-) is there an alternative method? thanks

Comment: i also think that this is a php problem because all other pages using this code are displaying ok. i shall repost in php forum. many thanks for your help

Comment: Well, as I said, `"dept": "<?php echo addslashes($dept); ?>"` is nearly right, and OK if you don't have any newline characters in your value. Otherwise it's a bit of a pain as each newline character (including the obscure Unicode ones U+2028 and U+2029) needs separate escaping. `json_encode` really is preferable. Please kick your admin in the shins: PHP4 is obsolete and potentially dangerous.

Comment: i have tried another way. but can anyone tell me why this would cause a parse error? $json .= "dept: ["."\"".implode('","',explode(",",$dept))."\"."],\n";

Comment: btw bobince. i have issued am email to the admin re upgrade.

Comment: and the revised while statement.        $dept  = array();
$box = array();

$i = 0;
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
          $dept[] = $row['department'];
          $box[] = $row['custref'];
}

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is incorrect. It is formatted like this:

```
{
dept: '...'
box: '...'
}
```

It should be:

```
{
"dept": "..."
"box": "..."
}
```

The identifiers need quotation marks around them, and strings are enclosed in quotation marks, not apostrophes.

Answer (score 0):

RFC4627 defines the media type for JSON as "application/json".

Answer (score 0):

Your wrote

```
$json .= "dept: '".$dept.",'\n";
```

So,
1. You should add double quotes for key and value. 
2. There is no comma (,) after key value ends. You are adding it inside the quote. i.e. you code will create this json,

```
dept: 'department,'
```

See the place of comma there.

try this:

```
$json .= "\"dept\": \"".$dept."\",\n";
```